# bcrypt error while deploying rails app to ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt

am getting the following error while deploying my rails app to my ubuntu server

```
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue
```

I have tried `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` but that doest seem to work at all

any solution will be highly appreciated

Comment: without knowing why it can't install (the error will tell you where to look to see why), we can't really help you.

Comment: @peterson-samsam Can you post your log errors?

Answer (score 0):

Log files were never created, so there was nothing to show.

Anyway, I restarted my Ubuntu server and suddenly everything worked. Successfully deployed my rails app after restarting Ubuntu server